# Type safe tunneling of user data between method calls

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am developing an API allowing users to transfer data using a certain protocol. Throughout the communication, two events - EventA and EventB occur. B is optional, but strongly related to A. They occur in the sequence `(AB?)*`. This events are exposed to the user as a hook call to an interface:

```
interface IEventHandler {
    void eventAOccured(EventAData aData);
    void eventBOccured(EventBData bData);
}
```

Now I want the user to be able to pass some data about event A to the hook of event B while keeping the interface stateless. First I thought something like

```
interface IEventHandler<U> {
    U eventAOccured(EventAData aData);
    void eventBOccured(EventBData bData, U userData);
}
```

Unfortunately, as generics do not offer runtime information (not without reflection, at least) the API has no way to call `eventBOccured`, as the type of its second parameter is not known at compile time. Introducing a markerinterface and `U extends IMarker` solves this, but does not spare the upcast I wanted to avoid. IMHO if I would go with the upcast I could simply pass `Object` and get the same thing.

I am pretty sure (Java) generics are the wrong tool here. Am I missing something? How would you tackle the problem?

Comment: Would it be an option to pass the class (here`U`) along with the data to avoid reflexion ?

Comment: Instead of U I could pass an wrapper object with its class definition, but still the calling API could not refer to the generic type in any way, could it?

Answer (score 0):

I will do that way : 
package com.stackoverflow.user3590895.questions24098455;

```
//-------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.user3590895.questions24098455;

public class EventData implements IEventData{

    //default is type A
    private int type=IEventData.TYPE_A;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        System.out.print("Event [type:"+type+"]!");
        return type;
    }


}
//-------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.user3590895.questions24098455;

public interface IEventData {
    public static char TYPE_A='A';
    public static char TYPE_B='B';

    public int getType();
}

//-------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.user3590895.questions24098455;

public interface IEventHandler<U> {
    U eventOccured(IEventData data);
}
```

**Use case:** 
- make a call of event (with event of you choice
- api catch event and can know his type by calling function getType. 
- if you are an eventData B, you can herit of EventData and make a new EventData for B Type. You can add some specific function for EventDataB, and specific datas also.

give me feedback.

Comment: The problem that the calling API does not know the type `U` and thus cannot pass it back to the event handler still remains, doesn't it?

Comment: may I ask you to give me the call of this API in order to understand better this.

Comment: `IMarker u = handler.eventAOccured(...)`
`handler.eventBOccured(..., u) << this cannot work, as the second parameter is a supertype of IMarker`

Comment: with the code inthe answer, I can perform `IMarker u = handler.eventOccured(eventA) handler.eventOccured(enventB)`. Isn't it right?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you could use a wrapper around you data containing its class definition. Something like

```
class Wrapper<U extends IMarker> {
    U data;
    Class<U> clazz;
    // constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Your event interface would be

```
interface IEventHandler<U extends IMarker> {
    Wrapper<U> eventAOccured(EventAData aData);
    void eventBOccured(EventBData, Wrapper<U> user data);
}
```

That way, `Wrapper` class is known, and API can call it without problem. And in `eventBOccured` you have the right type for your upcast.

Comment: How can you upcast the generic type of the wrapper? I am still thinking that this cannot be done because the API has no class information about user data class. Though I am interesred how to interpret the error message:

`The method eventBOccured(Wrapper<capture#3-of ? extends IMarker>) in the type IEventHandler<capture#3-of ? extends IMarker> is not applicable for the arguments (Wrapper<capture#4-of ? extends IMarker>)`

Comment: You have no reason to upcast the wrapper. But you have a `U` data that you can safely upcast because the wrapper says that the real class is `clazz`.